# Sensing Two Consecutive Strings in String

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, sorting, search

If I have `aaabbbccc`, I'd like to change them in to `a3b3c3`.

I am using if statement for this.. but it looks too inefficient.

Maybe Regex would be helpful, but regex for searching only the consecutives is possible?

if I have `aaabbbcccaaa` then I'd like to change them `a3b3c3a3` list this.. which means the algorithm only search the "consecutives and count them" change into integer.

Any hint to proceed would be appreciated.

```
def comp(string):


index = []

for i in range(len(string)):
    try:
        if string[i] is not string[i+1]:
            index.append(i)
    except:
        pass

first = string[index[0]] + str(index[0]+1)
print(first)

message_comp = [first]
for i in range(1, len(message_comp)):
    message_comp.append(message[index[i]]*(index[i-1]+1))

final = ''.join(message_comp)

return final
```

Answer (score 2):

**[`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby)**:

> Make an iterator that returns consecutive keys and groups from the iterable

```
import itertools
x = 'aaabbbcccaaa'
groups = [i + str(len([*j])) for i, j in itertools.groupby(x)]

# ['a3', 'b3', 'c3', 'a3']
```

**`join`** to finish up:

```
''.join(groups)

# a3b3c3a3
```

If needed, **`replace`** to remove `1`:

`''.join(groups).replace('1', '')` instead of `''.join(groups)`

Comment: What is the most simple way to deprecate 1? such as for abbccc, not a1b2c3 but ab2c3

Comment: @Beverlie updated my answer, just use `''.join(groups).replace('1', '')` at the end.

Comment: @chriz what does [*j] mean?

Comment: `[*j]` unpacks the contents of `j` (a groupby object) into a list, so that you can check the length of it.

Comment: More about unpacking here: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/packing-and-unpacking-arguments-in-python/

Comment: I've tried following to learn your syntax i =list(itertools.groupby('aaabb'))[0] then  i[1]  is <itertools._grouper at 0x1074ba2e8>. but if I try len(list(*i[1])) it returns 0 not 3 of a's number. why so?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe itertools groupby?

```
from itertools import groupby
s = "aaabbbcccaaa"
groups = groupby(s)
a = [(label, sum(1 for _ in group)) for label, group in groups]
b = [i for sub in a for i in sub]
print("".join(map(str,b)))

output: a3b3c3a3
```